# A question about isomorphic of dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A question about isomorphic of dihedral group

A) Is $D_4 $ is isomorphic to $S_4$?

B) Is $D_{50}$ is isomorphic to $D_5 \times D_5$

C) Is $D_4 \times D_4$ is isomorphic to $C_4 \times C_4 \times C_4$

**my attempt:** For A)  every element of S4 has order of 4 or less, whereas
D12 has elements of order 6 and 12. Since they have different orders on their elements, these two groups cannot be isomorphic.

But i don't about B) and C)

Comment: Is question B correct?

Comment: @learnmore..sorry i am edited now

Comment: A similar line of reasoning to what you have done in part a) will work for b) and c).

Comment: @Mathily..yes , but i cant find the those elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D_4$ has eight elements, but $S_4$ has 24.

$D_{50}$ has 100 elements, and so does $D_5 \times D_5$.  But $D_{50}$ has an element of order 50; $D_5 \times D_5$ does not.

$D_{4} \times D_4$ has 64 elements and so does  $C_4 \times C_4 \times C_4$.  But $D_{4} \times D_4$ is nonabelian; $C_4 \times C_4 \times C_4$ is abelian.

Comment: ..i just added my question